# border-image left only

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a border-image but only to the left side of an element. I've tried border-left-image to no avail. If you look at [this site](http://tdg.thesn.net) you'll notice at the footer I have an element with a double border on both sides, when I only want it on the left.

Here is my current styling for that element:

```
    border-style: solid;
    -moz-border-image: url(/assets/dist/images/footer-border.png) 8 fill stretch repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(/assets/dist/images/footer-border.png) 8 fill stretch repeat;
    -o-border-image: url(/assets/dist/images/footer-border.png) 8 fill stretch repeat;
    border-image: url(/assets/dist/images/footer-border.png) 8 fill stretch repeat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to just absolutely position it as a background image and repeat it on the y-axis instead. Might not be the best solution but it works.

Answer (score 4):

border image has a width property. set the width for (respectively) top, right, bottom, left:

```
border-image-width: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
```